# meteor-tabular export data wih html5 export buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, meteor, export-to-csv

I'm using tabular to view data from collection in a table but when I need to export data with html5 export buttons with button (csvhtml5 )it shows only the length of data visible in the table not all the data in the collection.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular#features
https://datatables.net/reference/button/csvHtml5

is there anyway to make it export all data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by how Tabular handles retrieving data; it only holds the subscribed documents not the entire collection.

> By default, a normal Meteor.subscribe is used for the current page's table data. This subscription is stopped and a new one replaces it whenever you switch pages. This means that if your table shows 10 results per page, your client collection will have 10 documents in it on page 1. When you switch to page 2, your client collection will still have only 10 documents in it, but they will be the next 10.

To circumvent this problem, we came up with a hacky solution that involved modifying `tabular` and `datatables.net-buttons` but it's too ugly to share, so my two cents to use vanilla datatables and pass it all the data, and it'll handle exporting for you, neatly.

Here's something to get you started: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41493/how-to-install-datatables-with-meteor-js-bootstrap-3

Comment: Thank you. I will try to export it in other way